# JS: How to divide number into categories? (0-100, 101-500,...)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a custom pricing page for a company. And they have 'breaks' in their calculation for the prices. (Business 2 business)

Example: 
0 - 100 employees = price 12
101 - 500 employees = price 4
501 - 1001 employees = price 2
1001 - 1001 employees = price 2
..

Now when the amount of employees is 1250, then it has to calculate what category it is in, and starts from there to last category to calculate price / category -->

Example: 
1250 employees
0 - 100 = (100 - 1250) * 12
101 - 500 = (500 - 1150) * 4
501 - 1000 = (the rest that remains; 650) * 2

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaSWG.png)
So could you guys maybe push me in the right direction?

Any help is really appreciated!

*EDIT:*

With the answers below I rewrote what I needed. For people who need to use it in future projects. I shall post it here:

Null gets filled by the product prices.

```
var boundaries        =
        [
            [0, null],
            [100, null],
            [500, null],
            [1000, null],
            [3000, null],
            [5000, null],
            [10000, null]
        ];
    var calculator = {
    pricing      : {},
    solutionTotal: null,
    init         : function () {
    },
    calculate    : function (id) {
        var sum               = 0;
        var count             = globalNumber;
        var $selectedSolution = $('li[data-id=' + id + ']');

        //fill up prices in boundaries array by id
        for (var x = 0; x < boundaries.length; x++) {
            boundaries[x][1] = $selectedSolution.attr('data-price-' + boundaries[x][0]);
        }

        //use boundaries array and prices
        for (var i = boundaries.length; i > 0; i--) {
            if (count > boundaries[i - 1][0]) {
                sum += (count - boundaries[i - 1][0]) * boundaries[i - 1][1];
                count = boundaries[i - 1][0];
            }
        }
        this.solutionTotal = sum;
        console.log('sum is ', this.solutionTotal);
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about the calculation. A price break structure normally works as a whole, whereas you seem to be working on a cumulative price structure.

Comment: Also, Could you post what you tried or the data model? Thanks

Comment: are you sure, that 101-500 is 500 parts and not just 400?

Comment: @dloeda I used the pricebreak module at the moment. But it doesnt add the previous 'breaks' it just looks at which category and then just does price * quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var em = 1250;
if (em > 1000) {sum4 = (em-1000)*2; em=1000;}
if (em > 500) {sum3 = (em-500)*2; em=500;}
if (em > 100) {sum2 = (em-100)*4; em=100;}
if (em > 0) {sum1 = em*12;}
console.log(sum1,sum2,sum3,sum4);

//print out: 1200,1600,1000,500
```

Comment: This may work, let me see if I can use this. I will get back to you!

Comment: why change em at the end? and the if statements need a 2nd condition. if em = 1250 it will fill all four sum variables. 2nd if should be if (em > 500 && em <= 1000)

Comment: i changed em when calculated sum in that category, so we need to calculate sum for smaller category, ex: sum in (1001~) -> sum in(501~1000)->sum in(100~500) ->sum in (0~100). And if em=1250 i think no problem

Comment: Hi man! I changed it up a bit to be dynamical with the prices and boundaries. But that it! 

Muchos gracias!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array with the daltas for the next price and calculate the price by using the amount and if it is not zero, then take the next element of the array and check against aunf adjust the amount and calculating the price for the actual amount.

```js
var prices = [[100, 12], [400, 4], [500, 2], [Infinity, 2]],
    amount = 1250,
    index = 0,
    price = 0;

while (amount && index < prices.length) {
    if (amount < prices[index][0]) {
        price += amount * prices[index][1];
        amount = 0;
    } else {
        price += prices[index][0] * prices[index][1];
        amount -= prices[index][0];
    }
    index++;
}

console.log(price);
```

The same as above with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var prices = [[100, 12], [400, 4], [500, 2], [Infinity, 2]],
    amount = 1250,
    price = 0;

prices.some(function (a) {
    if (amount <= a[0]) {
        price += amount * a[1];
        return true;
    } else {
        price += a[0] * a[1];
        amount -= a[0];
    }
});

console.log(price);
```

Comment: Hi Nina, thank you for your code! I don't seem to understand it fully tho. Can you elaborate shortly? Thanks already!

Comment: The final result of what I'm trying to achieve is just a global price. So as soon as a product is selected, it has to calculate the price for that solution and display it. 
Nothing more. If I have that I'm building the next steps of the pricing page.  (generating docx/styling/etc)

Comment: I was just testing this out, and I get 4500 not 4300?

Comment: now you get the wantted result, which was missing in the question, btw.